# How to execute .pyw file?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I tried

```
> pyinstaller mycode.pyw
```

but when I click on the executable file, my script doesn't run.
As it is a test code, it should only create a txt file.

Comment: A `.pyw` is supposed to be a regular python file, just tailored to run on windows specifically. That is, you can do a simple `python mycode.pyw` to run it.

Comment: @FadyAdel your pyinstaller command is OK but there may be several issues with the .exe. Run it from a command prompt and review the output